# SQL Table formation dynamic column creation

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have a sql table with attributes

att1, att2, combination_result

which has a binary relationship
att1+att2 => combination_result

Now I need to evaluate many attributes instead of just binary combinations

like att1+att2+att3 => combination_result

There could be 1000's of attributes.

How do I best address this? (Creating 1000 columns is not good I think).

MORE INFO:

Examples of Attributes

1. Attendance
2. Interaction
3. Participation
4. attitude

Example of Table values

Attendance, Participation => Increased Score

Interaction, Attitude => Decreased score

So I had Binary comparison table.

Now I have multiple features

Attendance, Attitude, Participation => Decreased score

..
..
I do not know how to design schema for this.

Database used in SQL (SQLITE)

Comment: [1] what db are you using (so we can check for native features) [2] can you provide an example of what are you trying to do? [what you're doing seems wrong, maybe if you provide more details, we can come with another solution for your problem]. My feeling is that you should be returning rows, not columns here Thanks

Comment: MSFT handles this in AD by using position of a binary to matter; but instead of returning a binary it returns a decimal value.  Which you could do here as well.